# Unable to create a databricks cluster in a workspace

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, databricks

I am new to Databricks. I am trying to provision databricks cluster on GCP but unable to do so as I am getting the status as pending. This is what is being displayed `No active Google Kubernetes Engine cluster found for workspace. Retrying Google Kubernetes Engine cluster creation`. I have also enabled the required APIs like `compute.googleapis.com`, `container.googleapis.com`, `deploymentmanager.googleapis.com`, `iam.googleapis.com` to spin up the databricks cluster.

I am attaching a screenshot for your reference.[image]

Answer (score 1):

this error is due to lack of quotas or not reaching the minimum, services such as: compute.googleapis.com./cpus need a minimum of 60 quotas, compute.googleapis.com/n2_cpus minimum 50 and compute.googleapis.com/ssd_total_storage 7.5 ALSO. after setting this try creating the custer again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I figured it out but forgot to update. Yes, it's because of the quota limit.